# Announcing a Pro Tempore Moderator election

Tags: discussion, election

**Summary**: Operations Research Stack Exchange will begin the nomination stage for [a special election](https://or.stackexchange.com/election/1) on **July 29** to bring in your three inaugural pro-tem moderators.

For full details of the process, see [the announcement on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/314459/experimenting-with-pro-tempore-elections). The timeline:

- Starting on July 29, users can [nominate themselves](https://or.stackexchange.com/election/1). Users can also ask questions on meta for potential moderators to answer. (Use the [discussion](/questions/tagged/discussion) and [election](/questions/tagged/election) tags.)
- On August 5, if there are four or more candidates, we'll run an election. If not, I'll simply appoint the candidates. (There's a small chance we'll need to [remove a nomination](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/274114/lets-disallow-nominations-from-people-whove-been-suspended-in-the-past-year), but I doubt that will come up.)
- If there is an election, I'll announce the results on meta on August 13.

If you have any questions about the process, please stick them in an answer here.